# Intellij14 and "Please Provide Missing Values dialog box"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to run simple SQL scripts with type casting on a PostgreSQL db via IntelliJ 14. I have problem with type casting. E.g., consider the following trivial query:

```
select '100'::INT;
```

Everytime the following annoying panel appears:

[image]

Clearly, the message "Please Provide Missing Values..." drives me crazy, since `INT` is not a parameter, but just a type casting. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ lets you define what counts as a parameter and what does not.

Go to "Settings" -> "Tools" -> "Database" and have a look at the "Custom SQL parameters". You probably want to remove `\:\w+`, as it's probably triggered by your type cast.

[image: IntelliJ database settings]

Have a look at the documentation for more information about the parameters: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/11/database-language-injection-configuration/

Comment: I removed all the string literals and now it is working. Strange thing is that the checkbox was off. So I don't know why IntelliJ was using them by default!

Comment: Strange indeed. I recommend you report this as a bug.